# Prev check with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Need a little help from you guy's. I am making a check where element is. First if statement is working , but else if is not... I have tried even something like this but it doesn't work:

```
else if(($('.current').prev().hasClass('green')){
    alert('Green is Before the current Picture');
     }
```

I want to accomplish this: if green is before class "current" alert "Green is Before the current Picture's".
Can someone help me out? Thank you!

Here is [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zresC/)

I have this code:

```
 var $green=$('.green:not(:nth-child(6))');

$('.greencontroll').click(function(){

  if($green.next($('.current').length)){
   alert('Green is After the current Picture');
}

  else if($green.prev($('.current').length)){
      alert('Green is Before the current Picture');
      }
```

Comment: Green's after the picture in your jsFiddle, that's why it's not saying it's before the picture...

Comment: I know, when I try to click two times on the next slide it will still alert that is "Green After the current picture"  that's the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the elements are siblings:

```
var $elements = $('.current').siblings().andSelf();

var curIndex = $elements.index(".current");
var greenIndex = $elements.index(".green");

if(curIndex > greenIndex){
   // before
}
```

The problem with your code is that `prev` just gets the sibling immediately prior to the element, not all prior siblings.

Comment: @SheikhHeera the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/  though in retrospect I think `.parent().children()` could be slightly more efficient, not sure.